# does invertibility of product imply invertibility of each term of product?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, inverse, products

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space and the product $T_1T_2 \in B(\mathcal{H})$ is invertible. Does this imply that both $T_1, T_2$ are invertible ? I am unable to prove this since, unlike the finite dimensional case, injectivity or surjectivity alone does not imply invertibility. I am of course assuming that both both $T_1,T_2 \in B(\mathcal{H})$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Let $H$ be a separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, and let $\{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis. Let $T_1 \in B(H)$ be given by $T_1 e_k = e_{2k}$, and let $T_2 \in B(H)$ be given by
$$
 T_2 e_k = \begin{cases} e_{k/2} &\text{if $k$ is even,}\\ 0 &\text{if $k$ is odd;} \end{cases}
$$
observe, indeed, that $\|T_1\| = \|T_2\| = 1$. Then $T_1$ is injective but not surjective, $T_2$ is surjective but not injective, and yet $T_2 T_1 = \operatorname{id}_H$. The essential point is that $V := \operatorname{span}\{e_{2k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a proper closed subspace of $H$ even though $V \cong H$ as Hilbert spaces (via $T_1$ as a unitary isomorphism $H \to V$), all of which is ultimately possible precisely because $H$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: The context in which I asked the question was the following:  Is the product $(T- \lambda_1 I)\cdots(T-\lambda_n I)$ invertible if and only if each $(T-\lambda_i I)$ is invertible. It turns out that the statement is true, and it works because of the fact that the product commutes. In my first question above however, the operators are different, and hence that works out differently.